# Month Grouping in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Well i have 2 files in groovy format.

First is Transfer.Groovy

```
package com.revengtest


class Transfer {

Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
Date transferDate
String number
Float latitude
Float longitude
TransactionMaster transactionMaster
Warehouse warehouseSource
Warehouse warehouseDest
String reffNo
String toString() { return number } 

static hasMany = [transferItems: TransferItem]
static belongsTo = [TransactionMaster, Warehouse]

static mapping = {
    version false
}

static constraints = {

    transferDate nullable: true
    number nullable: true, maxSize: 45
    longitude nullable: true
    latitude nullable: true

}
//this is the code to automatic create the number in transfer
def beforeInsert(){

    Integer count= Transfer.count()+1
    Integer width= transactionMaster.width


    String c = sprintf("%0${width}d",count)

    number = transactionMaster.code+"/"+c
    }


}
```

Next is TransactionMaster.groovy

```
package com.revengtest

class TransactionMaster {

static constraints = {

    numbering(inList:["Monthly","Yearly"])

}
String code
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
String name
String numbering
Integer width
TransferType transferType

String toString() { return name } 

static hasMany = [transfers: Transfer]
static belongsTo = [TransferType]


}
```

And here i got pic from my web

this is the transaction master page [image: master page]

this is transfer page ->
[image: transfer page]

Now the problem, i want to make the number return to 0001 when the month change, so if the date is 2013-08-14 the number should be start again from 0001.
In my code it's still 0003, any idea how to make it happen?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy`:

```
grouped = transfers.groupBy { it.transferDate.month }
```

and then you could iterate over the grouped elements.

You could place it in `TransactionMaster`s `beforeUpdate` and/or `beforeInsert` method.

```
def beforeInsert() {
    grouped.each { month, transfers ->
        if(transfers.size() == 1) {
            transfers[0].number = "0001"
         } else {
            transfers.eachWithIndex { t, idx ->
                t.number = "${idx}".padLeft(4,"0") // will prepend zeros before number
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first, where should i type this code? in transactionmaster.groovy or the transfer.groovy | then how to make the value start from zero again when it reach new month? for example in July it has number 0049, then in August it should be 0001, not 0050, but thanks before for your answer sir :)

Comment: it displays error:
HTTP Status 500 - Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.internal.SESSION_FACTORY_HOLDER': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectcom.revengtest.TransactionMaster

Comment: beside that,i place the code for auto-numbering in Transfer.Groovy, not in TransactionMaster.groovy, maybe you have solution again sir? thanks before..

Comment: Well, as the numbering of the Transfers depends on other transfers in a set hold by TransactionMaster it is best, when you call the numbering routine from there as you have to remember the numbering state across the loop. You could probably refer to the TransactionMasters Transger collection from each Transfer, but this will be no good idea.